# Shared Elements Between Fragments

Tags: android, animation, android-fragments, android-transitions

I have a ViewPager that is a shared element between two fragments. The viewpager hosts some images and the animation applied is the Explode animation. The images have to be loaded from the internet.

When transitioning between the two fragments, there doesn't appear to be any animation happening. Does the animation work best for standalone images or other elements such as buttons and other views only?

Comment: Fragments are not the problem for transitions in the view pager, it should work fluently.

Comment: @Ben-J so the delay before Picasso loads the image into the imageview is insignificant and shouldnt affect how the transition and animations work?